# How to set up testing automation with the TestNG+gradle+Allure+Zalenium in GitLab?

Tags: gradle, gitlab, allure, zalenium

We have tests for **TestNG** that run through the **gradle** task and then you can generate a report in **Allure**.
Later we added the possibility to run tests in the container in **Zalenium**.

How can I set up test runs in **GitLab**?

Maybe there are some tutorials or working examples on github?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not really a clear question, since you are looking for a GitLab CI tutorial, I would just recommend to Google something related to that. Go over a simple example and build up from there.

Comment: We have also k8s, maybe do we know how integrate this with k8s ?